# EF- Both '' and '' are mapped to the table ''. All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Got the following exception with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.9` when running `Add-Migration` command.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Both '' and
> '' are mapped to the table ''. All the
> entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be
> mapped to different tables. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2130430 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception happens if you use `Table-per-type configuration` for example and do not create a map for the individual tables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration

Solved it by adding this to `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NewEntity>().ToTable("NewEntities");
```